# export functions in linux kernel to linux modules

Tags: linux, module, kernel

I am trying to allocate a big chunk of memory in linux module, and `kalloc` can't do it.

I understood that the only way of doing it uses  `alloc_bootmem(unsigned long size)` but I can allocate it only from linux kernel and not from the module. 
So I came up with this solution:

I will add function to the kernel that allocates memory and returns pointer to it. 
Then I will use this function in the module.

Is this the best solution for my situation? As I said, I need to deal with a big chunk of memory...

Also, how can I export a function from the kernel and use it in the module? How to make the pointer to the data chunk available to the module?

Comment: Look in the kernel source for uses of EXPORT_SYMBOL().

Answer (score 1):

This is what you do:

In the kernel file that has the symbol add the following header before the symbol

```
#include <linux/module.h>

<here there should be the declaration of the symbol>
```

Now add this after the symbol

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL(<name of the symbol>);
```

For example:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
int (*foo)(void);

EXPORT_SYMBOL(foo);
```

Done!

Comment: I verified this on Centos 6.3 so it may be a bit different on another version but the idea is right.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use alloc_bootmem when in module. Try `alloc_pages` or `vmalloc` when you don't need continuous space.